# Kolmogorov Backward Equation for Itô diffusion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be the solution of the SDE
$$
X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \mu(s,X_s) \,ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s,X_s) \,dB_s, \quad t\ge 0 
$$
where $\mu(s,x)$ and $\sigma(s,x) $ are Lipschitz continuous in $x$ uniformly in $t$.
My question is related to the last argument in a proof (in the book of Klebaner - Introduction to Stochastic Calculus in Section 6.2 on p.154) showing that 
$u(t,x):=\mathbb{E}(g(X_T)|X_t=x)$ solves
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial_t}u(t,x) + \mu(t,x)\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}u(t,x)
+ \frac{\sigma^2(t,x)}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(t,x)=0.\qquad (*)
$$
In the proof it is shown that
$$
\int_0^t \frac{\partial}{\partial_t}u(s,X_s) + \mu(s,X_s)\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}u(s,X_s)
+ \frac{\sigma^2(s,X_s)}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(s,X_s) \,ds = 0 \quad \mathbb{P}-a.s.
$$
for every $t\ge 0$. Now it is concluded that the PDE $(*)$ above holds. Why is that?

Comment: I want us to be on the same wavelength here. which one is the PIDE? If by PIDE, you mean $\int^t_0 ... \text{d}s$, then surely the fact $u(t,x)$ solves the PDE pointwise, this should mean on integrand is true for every value of $(t,x)$, we now just take $x=X_s$.

Comment: @Lost1 Sorry, I should have written PDE (since the SDE is not driven by a jump process). With PDE I mean
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial_t}u(t,x) + \mu(t,x)\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}u(t,x)
+ \frac{\sigma^2(t,x)}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(t,x)=0.
$$

Comment: I see... this is actually a brilliant question and I actually wondered about the same thing but I think it is unlikely to be answered. (unless someone like Did see this) I think it might be worth trying to post this on the quantitative finance forum? if you do, please link me

Comment: (and PIDE is yucky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151669/kolmogorov-backward-equation-question/151685?noredirect=1#151685

I asked this question on math overflow. For the answer, please open this link.